# Selenium hover code works in Chrome not Edge

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, action

```
public void Hover()
{
    Actions action = new Actions(BrowserWindow.Instance.Driver);
    action.MoveToElement(WebElement).Perform();
}
```

This is working in Chrome. Not Edge. I have confirmed with the developer that I am "hovering" over the correct element.

```
WebElement elem = yourWebDriverInstance.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='goog-menu goog-menu-vertical uploadmenu density-tiny']/input"));
String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";

((JavascriptExecutor) yourWebDriverInstance).executeScript(js, elem);
```

Which also failed to work. Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

**More info.**

This is also failing on Firefox. I saw an article about out of date selenium drivers. I have JUST installed both geckodriver and set the Edge driver to auto update according to the documentation. I do not believe I have out of date drivers.

**More info take 2**

Calling code is

```
public static void DoCloseActiveTabEntire()
{
    Element tab = new Element(byTab);
    tab.Hover();

    // CLose button is not clickable. Cannot use standard BUTTON for find
    Button close = new Button(byClosePanelButton);
    close.Click();
}
```

If I set a break point at button close... after the hover attempt, I notice that moving my mouse over the "tab" also does not cause the button to be visible.

Comment: Looks, like its known issue, probably still not fixed. 
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4605

Comment: Confusing since the comment you linked to says "Should be supported in release 10586" and this driver is many versions past that.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. I also had an issue with EDGE, when I was trying to open some special link, but it was crashing. It was known issue I found reported bug on Microsoft web site were it says, that issue is fixed in EDGE 15, but it's still not fixed even in version 18, so idk.

Comment: Did you try hovering on nested elements or parent element? The 'onhover' event might be handled on a different element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I don't know why I thought the build().perform() did the job. I know it worked ONCE. What I wound up doing is keeping the hover code the same.

```
        public void Hover()
    {
        Actions action = new Actions(BrowserWindow.Instance.Driver);
        action.MoveToElement(WebElement).Build().Perform();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

    }
```

I changed the calling code which attempts to close the panel/page whatever I want to call it to this:

```
        public static void DoCloseActiveTabEntire()
    {
        // So there is a defect in EDGE whereby the behavior of the code containted in the hover on the tab executes without
        // error but the action underneath does not occur. So in Edge, callng the hover method of the TAB as seen in the else condition 
        // below does nto display the CLOSE button which needs to be clicked.
        // So for Edge, javascript is used to display the button directly.
        IWebElement close;

        if (BrowserWindow.Instance.Browser == BrowserWindow.Browsers.Edge)
        {
            close = BrowserWindow.Instance.Driver.FindElement(byClosePanelButton);
            string js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible'; arguments[0].style.display='inline';";
            IWebDriver driver = BrowserWindow.Instance.Driver;
            IWebElement element = close;
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(js, element);
        }
        else
        {
            Element tab = new Element(byTab);
            tab.Hover();
            close = new Button(byClosePanelButton).WebElement;
        }
        close.Click();
    }
```

For me, I am happy that the thing can be closed. I don't care that much whether the hover achieves it.

Answer (score 1):

This is weird. But replace

```
action.MoveToElement(WebElement).Perform();
```

with

```
action.MoveToElement(WebElement).Build().Perform();
```

And it works. I read that the Build is built into Perform. But I was kinda just smacking at it hoping something fell out. And it worked.

Comment: Well color me confused. It had worked. Not it is no longer working. Again, Edge only. The "hover" code executes without error. But the button that is supposed to be made visible is not causing its click to error.

Answer (score 0):

### `perform()`

[perform()](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#perform--) is the convenience method for performing the actions without calling `build()` first.

---

### `build()`

[build()](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#build--) generates a composite action containing all actions so far, ready to be performed and additionally also resets the internal builder state, so subsequent calls to `build()` will contain fresh sequences.

---

### This usecase

In your usecase, you have invovoked `perform()` just after `moveToElement(WebElement)` without generating the composite action to be performed using `build()`.

---

### Solution

A straight forward solution would be to invoke `build()` before `perform()` as follows:

```
public void Hover()
{
    Actions action = new Actions(BrowserWindow.Instance.Driver);
    action.moveToElement(WebElement).build().perform();
}
```

Comment: Hoping to upvote all y'all helpful peeps. But while it worked for a handful of attempts, it is now failing. The hover code executes without error. But the button that is supposed to be made visible is not causing its click to fail. Edge only.